# Sum of abs of negative eigenvalues divided by sum of abs of all eigen values.If the result is convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $\lambda_1 (X)\geq \lambda_2 (X)\geq\ldots\geq\lambda_n (X)$ denote the eigenvalues of a matrix $X\in S^n$.

Let $f(X)= \sum_{i\colon λ_i<0}|\lambda_i(X)|$  and $g(X)= \sum_i|\lambda_i (X)|$.

Is $h(X)=f(X)/g(X)$ a convex function?

Comment: Please write your question clear and right.